# PassportJS + NodeJS: Does not redirect after success or fail gives 404 page

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, passport.js

I'm trying to implement PassportJS local, facebook, twitter & google authentication + saving to online mongolab mongodb database. Registering or log in work fine, as well as saving to the database. As soon as it's a succes it should redirect to /profile page, if it fails it should go back to the /login page or /register page. Neither work, they both give me 404 error page.

The file that it should redirect to ( /profile ) is accessable & works fine. It just won't redirect succes or even when failed.

Any help would be great.

## Passport.js

```
// load all the things we need
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;
var TwitterStrategy  = require('passport-twitter').Strategy;
var GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth').OAuth2Strategy;

// load up the user model
var User = require('../data/schema/user');

// load the auth variables
var configAuth = require('./auth');

module.exports = function(passport) {


    // used to serialize the user for the session
    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        done(null, user.id);
    });

    // used to deserialize the user
    passport.deserializeUser(function (user, done) {
        User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
            done(null, user);
        });
    });

    // =========================================================================
    // LOCAL LOGIN =============================================================
    // =========================================================================
    // we are using named strategies since we have one for login and one for signup
    // by default, if there was no name, it would just be called 'local'

    passport.use('login', new LocalStrategy({
            // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
            usernameField : 'email',
            passwordField : 'password'
            //passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
        },
        function (req, email, password, done)
        {
            // callback with email and password from our form
            process.nextTick(function(){

                // find a user whose email is the same as the forms email
                // we are checking to see if the user trying to login already exists
                User.findOne({ 'local.email' : email }, function (err, user) {
                    // if there are any errors, return the error before anything else
                    if (err)
                        return done(err);

                    // if no user is found, return the message
                    if (!user)
                        return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'No user found.')); // req.flash is the way to set flashdata using connect-flash

                    // if the user is found but the password is wrong
                    if (!user.validPassword(password))
                        return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Oops! Wrong password.')); // create the loginMessage and save it to session as flashdata

                    // all is well, return successful user
                    return done(null, user);
                });

            });


        }));

    // =========================================================================
    // LOCAL SIGNUP ============================================================
    // =========================================================================
    // we are using named strategies since we have one for login and one for signup
    // by default, if there was no name, it would just be called 'local'

    passport.use('signUp', new LocalStrategy({
            // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
            usernameField : 'email',
            passwordField : 'password',
            passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
        },
        function(req, email, password, done) {

            // asynchronous
            // User.findOne wont fire unless data is sent back

            process.nextTick(function() {

                // find a user whose email is the same as the forms email
                // we are checking to see if the user trying to login already exists
                User.findOne({ 'local.email' :  email }, function(err, user) {
                    // if there are any errors, return the error
                    if (err)
                        return done(err);

                    // check to see if theres already a user with that email
                    if (user) {
                        return done(null);
                    } else {

                        // if there is no user with that email
                        // create the user
                        var newUser            = new User();

                        // set the user's local credentials
                        newUser.local.email    = email;
                        newUser.local.password = newUser.generateHash(password);

                        // save the user
                        newUser.save(function(err) {
                            if (err)
                                throw err;
                            return done(null, newUser);
                        });

                    }

                });

            });

        }));



    // =========================================================================
    // FACEBOOK ================================================================
    // =========================================================================
    passport.use('facebook',new FacebookStrategy({

            // pull in our app id and secret from our authSchema.js file
            clientID        : configAuth.facebookAuth.clientID,
            clientSecret    : configAuth.facebookAuth.clientSecret,
            callbackURL     : configAuth.facebookAuth.callbackURL

        },

        // facebook will send back the token and profile
        function(token, refreshToken, profile, done) {

            // asynchronous
            process.nextTick(function() {

                // find the user in the database based on their facebook id
                User.findOne({ 'facebook.id' : profile.id }, function(err, user) {

                    // if there is an error, stop everything and return that
                    // ie an error connecting to the database
                    if (err)
                        return done(err);

                    // if the user is found, then log them in
                    if (user) {
                        return done(null, user); // user found, return that user
                    } else {
                        // if there is no user found with that facebook id, create them
                        var newUser            = new User();

                        // set all of the facebook information in our user model
                        newUser.facebook.id    = profile.id; // set the users facebook id
                        newUser.facebook.token = token; // we will save the token that facebook provides to the user
                        newUser.facebook.name  = profile.name.givenName + ' ' + profile.name.familyName; // look at the passport user profile to see how names are returned
                        newUser.facebook.email = profile.emails[0].value; // facebook can return multiple emails so we'll take the first

                        // save our user to the database
                        newUser.save(function(err) {
                            if (err)
                                throw err;

                            // if successful, return the new user
                            return done(null, newUser);
                        });
                    }

                });
            });

        }));

    // =========================================================================
    // TWITTER =================================================================
    // =========================================================================
    passport.use('twitte',new TwitterStrategy({

            consumerKey     : configAuth.twitterAuth.consumerKey,
            consumerSecret  : configAuth.twitterAuth.consumerSecret,
            callbackURL     : configAuth.twitterAuth.callbackURL

        },
        function(token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {

            // make the code asynchronous
            // User.findOne won't fire until we have all our data back from Twitter
            process.nextTick(function() {

                User.findOne({ 'twitter.id' : profile.id }, function(err, user) {

                    // if there is an error, stop everything and return that
                    // ie an error connecting to the database
                    if (err)
                        return done(err);

                    // if the user is found then log them in
                    if (user) {
                        return done(null, user); // user found, return that user
                    } else {
                        // if there is no user, create them
                        var newUser                 = new User();

                        // set all of the user data that we need
                        newUser.twitter.id          = profile.id;
                        newUser.twitter.token       = token;
                        newUser.twitter.username    = profile.username;
                        newUser.twitter.displayName = profile.displayName;

                        // save our user into the database
                        newUser.save(function(err) {
                            if (err)
                                throw err;
                            return done(null, newUser);
                        });
                    }
                });

            });

        }));

    // =========================================================================
    // GOOGLE ==================================================================
    // =========================================================================
    passport.use('google',new GoogleStrategy({

            clientID        : configAuth.googleAuth.clientID,
            clientSecret    : configAuth.googleAuth.clientSecret,
            callbackURL     : configAuth.googleAuth.callbackURL

        },
        function(token, refreshToken, profile, done) {

            // make the code asynchronous
            // User.findOne won't fire until we have all our data back from Google
            process.nextTick(function() {

                // try to find the user based on their google id
                User.findOne({ 'google.id' : profile.id }, function(err, user) {
                    if (err)
                        return done(err);

                    if (user) {
                        // if a user is found, log them in
                        return done(null, user);
                    } else {
                        // if the user isnt in our database, create a new user
                        var newUser          = new User();

                        // set all of the relevant information
                        newUser.google.id    = profile.id;
                        newUser.google.token = token;
                        newUser.google.name  = profile.displayName;
                        newUser.google.email = profile.emails[0].value; // pull the first email

                        // save the user
                        newUser.save(function(err) {
                            // if successful, return the new user
                            if (err) throw err;
                            return done(null, newUser);
                        });
                    }
                });
            });

        }));

};
```

## Route.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var passport = require('passport');

var Events = require('../data/schema/events.js');


    // =====================================
    // HOME PAGE (with login links) ========
    // =====================================
    router.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.render('landing');
    });

    // =====================================
    // EVENTS PAGE =========================
    // =====================================
    router.get('/events', function(req, res) {
        res.render('events');
    });

    // =====================================
    // GROUPS PAGE =========================
    // =====================================
    router.get('/groups', function(req, res) {
        res.render('groups');
    });

    // =====================================
    // PROFILE SECTION =====================
    // =====================================
    // we will want this protected so you have to be logged in to visit
    // we will use route middleware to verify this (the isLoggedIn function)
    router.get('/profile',isLoggedIn, function (req , res) {
        res.render('profile.jade',{ title: 'Profile', user: req.user});
    });

    // =====================================
    // LOGIN ===============================
    // =====================================
    // show the login form
    router.get('/login', function(req, res) {
        res.render('login');
    });

    // process the login form
    router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('login', {
        successRedirect : 'profile', // redirect to the secure profile section
        failureRedirect : 'login' // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
    }));

    //router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    //    passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    //        if (err) { return next(err); }
    //        // if user is not found due to wrong username or password
    //        if (!user) {
    //            return res.render('login', {
    //                //you can send a message to your view
    //                message: 'Invalid username or password'
    //            });
    //        }
    //        //passport.js has a logIn user method
    //        req.logIn(user, function(err) {
    //            if (err) { return next(err); }
    //
    //            return res.redirect('/');
    //        });
    //    })(req, res, next);
    //});

    // =====================================
    // FORGOTPW ============================
    // =====================================
    // show the login form
    router.get('/forgotpw', function(req, res) {
        res.render('forgotpw');
    });

    // process the signup form
    router.post('/forgotpw', passport.authenticate('signup', {
        successRedirect : '/profile', // redirect to the secure profile section
        failureRedirect : '/forgotpw' // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
    }));

    // =====================================
    // SIGNUP ==============================
    // =====================================
    // show the signup form
    router.get('/register', function (req, res) {
        res.render('register');
    });


    // process the signup form
    router.post('/register', passport.authenticate('signUp', {
        successRedirect : '/profile', // redirect to the secure profile section
        failureRedirect : '/register' // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
    }));

    // =====================================
    // LOGOUT ==============================
    // =====================================

    router.get('/logout', function(req, res){
        req.logout();
        res.redirect('/');
    });

    // =====================================
    // 404 =================================
    // =====================================

    router.get('/400',function(req,res){
        res.render('404');
    });

    // =====================================
    // 500 =================================
    // =====================================

    router.get('/500',function(req,res){
        res.render('500');
    });

// =============================================================================
// AUTHENTICATE (FIRST LOGIN) ==================================================
// =============================================================================

  // =====================================
  // FACEBOOK ROUTES =====================
  // =====================================
  // route for facebook authentication and login
    router.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope : 'email' }));

  // handle the callback after facebook has authenticated the user
    router.get('/auth/facebook/callback',
      passport.authenticate('facebook', {
        successRedirect : '/profile',
        failureRedirect : '/login',
          failureFlash: true
      }));

  // =====================================
  // TWITTER ROUTES ======================
  // =====================================
  // route for twitter authentication and login
    router.get('/auth/twitter', passport.authenticate('twitter'));

  // handle the callback after twitter has authenticated the user
    router.get('/auth/twitter/callback', passport.authenticate('twitter', {
        successRedirect : '/profile',
        failureRedirect : '/login',
        failureFlash: true
      }));


  // =====================================
  // GOOGLE ROUTES =======================
  // =====================================
  // send to google to do the authentication
  // profile gets us their basic information including their name
  // email gets their emails
    router.get('/auth/google', passport.authenticate('google', { scope : ['profile', 'email'] }));

  // the callback after google has authenticated the user
    router.get('/auth/google/callback',
      passport.authenticate('google', {
        successRedirect : '/profile',
        failureRedirect : '/login',
          failureFlash: true
      }));

    // =====================================
    // API EVENTS ROUTES ===================
    // =====================================

    router.get('/api/events', function (req, res) {
        Events.find(function (err, events) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);
            res.json(events);
        });
    });


// route middleware to ensure user is logged in
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated())
    return next();

  res.redirect('/');
}

module.exports = router;
```

## Login.html

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="form-body">
                <div class="col-md-4  col-md-offset-4">
                      <h2>Sign in with </h2>
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-sm-4"><a href="/auth/facebook" class="button btn-social facebook span-left btn-block"><span><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></span>Facebook</a></div>
                          <div class="col-sm-4"><a href="/auth/twitter" class="button btn-social twitter span-left btn-block"><span><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></span>Twitter</a></div>
                          <div class="col-sm-4"><a href="/auth/google" class="button btn-social googleplus span-left btn-block"><span><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></span>Google+</a></div>
                      </div>
                    <div class="section-divider"><span>OR</span></div>
                    <form class="loginForm" action="login.html" method="POST">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Email address</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder=" Email Address " required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Password</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control input-lg"  placeholder=" Password" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox"> Remember Me</label></div>
                        <div class="login-buttons"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-lg">Sign me in</button></div>
                        <div class="m-t-20">
                            <a class="add-info" href="forgotpw.html">Forgot your Password ?</a> | <a class="add-info" href="register.html"> Sign Up</a> | <a class="add-info" href="landing.html">Home</a>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

## Register.html

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="form-body">
                <div class="col-md-4  col-md-offset-4" ng-controller="valController">
                        <h2>Sign Up with</h2>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-4"><a href="#" class="button btn-social facebook span-left btn-block"><span><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></span>Facebook</a></div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4"><a href="#" class="button btn-social twitter span-left btn-block"><span><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></span>Twitter</a></div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4"><a href="#" class="button btn-social googleplus span-left btn-block"><span><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></span>Google+</a></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="section-divider"><span>OR</span></div>
                        <form name="registerForm" novalidate class="ng-pristine ng-valid-email ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-pattern ng-valid-validator">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label">Name</label>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6"><input type="text" name="firstName" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder=" First name"></div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6"><input type="text" name="lastName" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder=" Last name"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Email</label>
                                <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="mail@example.com" required  class="form-control input-lg">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label"> Password</label>
                                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder=" Password">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label">Re-enter Password</label>
                                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder=" Re-enter password">
                            </div>

                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-lg">Sign me Up</button>
                            <div class="m-t-20"><a class="add-info" href="landing.html">Home</a> | <a class="add-info" href="login.html">Back to Sign In</a></div>
                        </form>

                    <p>By clicking Sign Up, you agree to our Terms and that you have read our Cookie Use.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

## EDIT

Some screenshots with morgan logger from node: 
[Login with local strategy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kVxx.png)
[login with google strategy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqN85.png)

Comment: Try to change your `successRedirect: 'login'` in `router.post('/login'...` to start with `/` => `/login`

Comment: I have also tried this, but it has the same effect.Stil redirects me to 404 page

Comment: The *login with google strategy* image show many 404's. Why is that??

Comment: From my 404 page i can return to home page. But for some reason occaisionally it doesn't recognize anything anymore, its like it's been kicked from my server and doens't find any page anymore. If that makes sense. ( it stays on the 404 page )